# For which value is the matrix invertable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

Shouldn't I be able to multiply row 2 by $-1$ and add it to row 1 to get it more reduced?

Also, is this the way you solve all these problems? Just get it on reduced row echelon form and check the row with zeroes and set the equation equal to zero to find for which values it is not invertible?

Answer (score 4):

Why would you *want* to reduce any further? A triangular matrix is invertible exactly if the diagonal entries are all non-zero. There are multiple ways to see that - either watch what happens if you try to invert the matrix (you always can, as you realized - your proposed reduction would be the first step), or notice that the determinant of such a matrix is the product of its diagnoal entries.

Comment: Hmm I see. But looking at the original matrix, the diagonal are all not zero as long as $k$ is not zero?

Comment: @Paz "Such" referred to *triangular*. *Only* for triangular matrices is the determinant the product of the diagnoal entries!

Comment: Ah, sorry! Thanks!

Comment: @Paze $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 &0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & a_2 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_3 & ... & 0 \\
...&...&...&...&... \\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & a_n
\end{pmatrix}$$
$\implies$ $det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^na_i$

If one element on the diagonal is $0$ then the determinant is $0$ and the matrix is not invertible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to find the determinant of the original matrix, set it equal to zero and solve for $k$, since a matrix is not invertible if its determinant is zero.